# Can md5 return invalid result?

Tags: swift, cryptography, swift3

I have a CryptoSwift.framework in my project to convert String to md5. The result hash string is used to authorise on the server side. So all requests I send to this server are using this function and all worked fine until...

I receive a deviceToken object from the
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method. Then I convert it to a string with a "toHexString" function. And the I casually pass it to the APIHelper (my custom class for interactions with server side)

```
APIHelper.register(deviceToken: deviceToken.toHexString())
```

which is a simple wrapper around Alamofire request method adding some custom handling:

```
class func register(deviceToken: String)
    {
        request(.get, resource: FWWebRequests.registerToken, parameters: ["token": deviceToken]) { (object, result) in
            print(object as Any)
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

and the result from the server is always "Invalid hash string". But other methods using the same hashing just works fine. So the question is – can this be a hashing method problem. If not – what can it be?

Comment: Probably an encoding error. But you've got the advantage on us, you're able to debug,  we cannot and I'm not sure that there is enough info in your question to answer it.

Comment: A string cannot be directly passed to MD5. It needs to be encoded first. Are you sure CryptoSwift uses the encoding your are supposed to use for authorization?

Comment: And why do you think MD5 is the problem? There are so many steps involved in the authorization (e.g. building the hash string) that could go wrong. Show all the relevant code.

Comment: @Codo Building the hash string cannot be a problem cause it works fine on all other requests except this. I am starting to think there is a problem when  converting deviceToke data to hex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No *the algorithm* MD5 cannot produce an incorrect result. MD5 returns precisely 16 bytes with pseudo random values, meaning that the output cannot (easily) be distinguished from random.

Now what usually is a problem is that the output of MD5 is (or any other cryptographic function) is directly used as a string. Completely random values however may not match the assumed encoding (such as Windows-1252 / Latin or UTF-8). This means that data may be lost during encoding/decoding, which can lead to a string of a different size than 16 characters / bytes.

So the only thing that can be wrong (other than being null) is that the length is incorrect, or that the encoding of the hash value itself (into e.g. hexadecimals) is wrong. This could also be due to I/O problems of course (not reading enough data from a socket etc. etc.).